# How to set up background worker for PostgreSQL 11 server?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, backgroundworker

Recently I've been asigned to migrate part of the database from Oracle to PostgreSQL enviroment, as testing experiment. During that process, major drawback that occured to me was lack of simple way to implement parallelism which is required due to multiple design reasons, which aren't so relevant here. Recently I've discovered https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/bgworker.html following process, which occured to me as some way to solve my problems.

Yet not so truly, as I couldn't easly find any tutorial or example how to implement it even for a simple task as writing debugmessages into logger, while the process is running. I've tried some old ways, presented in some plugin specifications from version 9.3, but they weren't much of help.

I would like to know how to set up those workers properly. Any help would be appriciated.

PS: Also if some good soul found workaround to implement bulk collect for cursors into PostgreSQL it would be most kind of you, to share it.

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you want to use parallelism? That is too general a word for me. Why do you need "bulk collect"? To make translation from Oracle simpler or for performance reasons? Why don't you fetch row by row?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for bgworker that you linked to is for writing C code, which is probably not what you want.  You can use the [pg_background](https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background) extension, which will do what you want.  ora2pg will optionally use pg_background when converting oracle procedures with the autonomous transaction pragma.  The other option is to use dblink to open a connection to the current db.

Neither solution is great, but it's the only way to go if you need to store data in a table whether or not the enclosing transaction succeeds.  If you can get by with just putting stuff into the logs, you can use RAISE NOTICE instead.

As far as bulk collect for cursors go, I'm not sure exactly how you are using them, but set returning functions may help you.  Functions in postgres can return multiple rows without fiddling with cursors.

Comment: I am dealing with large datasets (50*10^6 records and more) and loading them to the memory, or even risking that while using cursor the whole procedure fails after 50% of data and the progres is lost is out of question. Also such occurances aren't that uncommon, and we still want to store what was made during that time. Because of it in oracle it was easy to split such tables into smaller ones, like 10 000 row parts and work on them one by one (or simultaneously, but you get the idea). But here I have some trouble doing so, as I don't see any straightforward way in copying that approach.

Comment: I don't know enough about what you are doing to really help, but it might be possible to work row by row or if you really want to batch stuff, you could put sets of data into a temporary table.